# Update records of image path in mysql

Tags: mysql, replace, phpmyadmin, insert, command

Are there any `mysql` commands to update records. I have a table, `products` and a column name, `image` that contains 2300 image paths. The paths are `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`.  I want to add `catalog/` before all records of the `image` column in the `products` table.

Are there any solution in phpmyadmin or Sql?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this ?

```
UPDATE products SET image = CONCAT('catalog/', image)
```